# How could I make Bruce Banner/Incredible Hulk as a valid character?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, hunter-the-vigil

After watching the Avengers, and getting back into Marvel Comics, I've wanted to make a **Hunter: the Vigil** character that, as close as possible, resembles the duality of "Bruce Banner/The Incredible Hulk".

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: It depends on which specific WoD creatures are allowed. Werewolves and vampires both have rage issues, though you should keep in mind that the kinds of things your character is likely to do when enraged have a very high chance of leading to morality loss and eventually your character becoming an NPC.

Comment: Depending on the power level of the Hulk in question, he'd almost be better modeled as a Scion, in fact.

Comment: @Nigralbus I believe that the question limits the scope to World of Darkness games; Scion, like Exalted and the Aeonverse, are separate games that share similar rules systems.

Comment: You could try out Marvel Heroic and save yourself a lot of effort.

Comment: @Jadasc It is definitely just for World of Darkness, I'm in a World of Darkness game and I want to play it. However, I'm running a Scion game and I can't believe I didn't think to have my player fight some Hulks. upvotes for you both.

Comment: Keep in mind you could do something "hulk-like" without actually shape-shifting. It would be like "translating Hulk into this another different set".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're looking to play someone who, under periods of stress or high emotion, turns into a super-strong creature driven by rage, a **werewolf** is an ideal choice. If you're looking for someone who can become nine feet tall, hugely muscled, and toss people a long way, you might also consider a changeling (a troll or an ogre, perhaps.)

Comment: Thank you very much; i don't own any of the changeling books, so apparently this now needs to change.

Answer (score 6):

There's a couple of different ways you can build a character like Bruce Banner/Hulk, even without dipping into supernatural templates.

## One body, two minds

The easiest way to have a split personality is to have a split personality.  The derangement 'Multiple Personality' from the core WoD book is severe-to-extreme, building from 'Irrationality' (when threatened, the character reacts with over-the-top counter-threats).  As written, the derangement causes swapped personalities based on a 'certain emotional stimuli' (such as overwhelming rage).  The second personality can have completely different skills than the first (moving dots from Science into Brawl, for example) and can have a one-to-three difference in total dots in Social Attributes.  (Hulk would likely loose all his Composure, and possibly move any Manipulation into Presence.)

If your character can have a supernatural template, both Vampires and Werewolves have mechanics causing them to loose control, though not always because of rage.  Geist can loose control to the spirit that is reanimating them, and spirits could theoretically try and possess/influence anyone (I'm shaky on the mechanics of this one, though).

## Breathtaking anger management issues

For the most part, in both the comics and the movies, Bruce is in control.  High Resolve and Composure are a must.  Vice of Rage, Virtue of Temperance, you've probably already done this.

## Hulk strongest there is

There are several supernatural abilities that can up a character's might, as well as a few mundane ones.  These are the ones I found/know of, split by required template:

- Human: Strong Back, Fighting Style: Boxing
- Vampire: Discipline of Vigor
- Werewolf: Garou (half-and-half) form, Blood Talon or Predator King tribes,  Gifts of Strength, Rage, Warrior's Moon
- Changeling: Contracts of Stone (first dot ups your Strength for a scene; second lets you break inanimate objects; third improves Strength for non-attack rolls (stacks); fifth ups Strength, Stamina, armor, Initiative, and reduces wound penalties), Contracts of Mirror (allows minor-to-major form shifts, depending on dots)

Comment: A comprehensive and well-presented answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

In the World of Darkness there can be almost anything you can imagine. You don't have to be restricted to which species WW published, especially if your character is unique.

I don't know much about Hulk, but he could be the result of a Technocracy or Pentex experiment, or maybe something similar to a fomori.

Comment: You're not taking into account the fact that most WoD DMs prefer to run groups that are all the same supernatural type.

Comment: Well, I do what I can with the information we have. Of course, the Storyteller must agree if the plan is doing a PC (instead of a NPC). Otherwise, the first thing should talking to the ST, knowing which kind of chronicle he is planning, and then if a similar character would work on that chronicle.

Comment: the Storyteller has mentioned that he would be okay with it, as long as I found something in the books to base my concept on. I definitely want it to be as close to from book as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the bygone bestiary from Mage: The sorceress crusade to do this kind of one-shot creatures.

You can feat shape shifting, incredible strength, endurance, invulnerabilities… although doing something like Hulk is going to be costly in points.